# How to change the SQL Server protocols via Command Prompt

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, protocols

I'm looking at doing a auto install for SQL Server 2017. I need the Named Pipes, TCP/IP and Shared Memory protocols to all be enabled.

I have not tried anything as I am not sure how to do this via cmd.

I am expecting the Shared Memory, Named Pipes and TCP/IP protocols to be enabled, not disabled after the auto install.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-2017#PowerShellProcedure

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a .ini file. In the .ini you specify

```
TCPENABLED="1"
NPENABLED="1"
```

Then in your bat file you add

```
"YourSQLSetupExeFile" /CONFIGURATIONFILE="YourIniFile" <plus any other parameters>
```

If every install uses the same parameters you can put them in the ini file. If those vary from one install to the next you can add the user entered values to the command line.

[Install SQL Server using a configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file?view=sql-server-2017)

You may also want to use NETSH advfirewall to add firewall rules (requires 'Run as Admin').